# `mkcert` command not found, after installing ddev

Tags: ddev

`mkcert` doesn't seem to be installed (or maybe not in the right path) on Ubuntu

```
ddev version
DDEV-Local version  v1.8.0                        
commit              v1.8.0                        
db                  drud/ddev-dbserver:v1.8.0-10.2
dba                 drud/phpmyadmin:v1.8.0        
ddev-ssh-agent      drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.8.0    
docker              18.09.5                       
docker-compose      1.21.2                        
domain              ddev.local                    
os                  linux                         
router              drud/ddev-router:v1.8.0       
web                 drud/ddev-webserver:v1.8.0
```

On Ubuntu 18

```
mkcert -install
zsh: command not found: mkcert
```

Comment: Oh, I see that on `ddev start` it gives a warning "mkcert may not be properly installed, please install it, `brew install mkcert nss`, `choco install -y mkcert`, etc. and then `mkcert -install`"

I thought I read in some issue that mkcert is now installed part of ddev.

Comment: if you are mac inter,

mkcert can be installed using brew,

`brew install mkcert`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use( a package manager homebrew on Linux or macOS, or use the ddev Windows installer, or use Chocolatey on WIndows) then mkcert gets installed for you. In all other cases you have to install it yourself, see https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Note that mkcert is optional. It's how we get the browser (and curl, etc) to trust the local development site using https. But of course, we can just use all the various means we've always used to ignore untrusted connections. But mkcert makes it really nice!

Note that on Linux `mkcert -install` may give you some extra instructions that you'll need to do for everything to work right, see [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#linux-mkcert-install-additional-instructions).

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. After `mkcert -install` I got success message (without any extra instructions), and restarted browsers. But  still when I try to go to `https://foo.ddev.local:8081/` I get an SSL error

Comment: If you didn't `ddev stop --all` please do that, and then `ddev start`. The ddev-router has to be restarted to get the new certs pushed into it. What browser are you using? I'm not having trouble with this on Ubuntu 18.04, both Chrome and Firefox are working. (Oh, please check to see if curl is working as well...)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to use chocolaty to get this in. Everything else kept failing..

> choco install mkcert